# Merge 2 php scripts

Tags: php, xml

I need some help with some php scripting. I wrote a script that parses an xml and reports the error lines in a txt file.

Code is something like this.

```
<?php


    function print_array($aArray)
    {
        echo '<pre>';
        print_r($aArray);
        echo '</pre>';
    }

    libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
    $doc = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'utf-8'); 
    $xml = file_get_contents('file.xml'); 
    $doc->loadXML($xml); 

    $errors = libxml_get_errors();
    print_array($errors);

    $lines = file('file.xml');
    $output = fopen('errors.txt', 'w');

    $distinctErrors = array();
    foreach ($errors as $error)
    {
        if (!array_key_exists($error->line, $distinctErrors))
        {
            $distinctErrors[$error->line] = $error->message;
            fwrite($output, "Error on line #{$error->line} {$lines[$error->line-1]}\n");

        }
    }

    fclose($output);

?>
```

The print array is only to see the errors, its only optional.
Now my employer found a piece of code on the net

```
<?php


//  test if the form has been submitted
if(isset($_POST['SubmitCheck'])) {
    // The form has been submited
    // Check the values!

        $directory = $_POST['Path'];

        if ( ! is_dir($directory)) {
              exit('Invalid diretory path');
                }
                else
                {
                  echo "The dir is: $directory". '<br />';
                        chdir($directory);

                        foreach (glob("*.xml") as $filename) {  
                        echo $filename."<br />";  
                        }  
              }
        }

        else {
    // The form has not been posted
    // Show the form
        ?>
        <form id="Form1" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">
            Path: <input type="text" name="Path"><br>
            <input type="hidden" name="SubmitCheck" value="sent">
            <input type="Submit" name="Form1_Submit" value="Path">
        </form>
        <?php
        }
?>
```

That basically finds all xmls in a given directory and told me to combine the 2 scripts.
That i give the input directory, and the script should run on all xmls in that directory and give reports in txt files.

And i don't know how to do that, i'm a beginner in PHP took me about 2-3 days to write the simplest script. Can someone help me with this problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Make a function aout of your code and replace all 'file.xml' to a parameter e.g. $filename.
In the second script where the "echo $filename" is located, call your function.